# Searching for multiple tags in in CQ5

Tags: java, search, aem

I'm using CQ5's SimpleSearch class to do a search implementation. One of my requirements is that I must check to see if a tag exists (for a lazy form of authentication). This is simple. The problem lies in that I wish to check to see if this tag is in the "jrc:content/cq:tags" or the "jcr:content/metadata/cq:tags." So for I have been unable to do so. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
    Predicate tagPredicate;
    Cookie[] tagsFromCookie = slingRequest.getCookies();

    tagPredicate = new Predicate("tags", "tagid");
    tagPredicate.set("property", "jcr:content/cq:tags");
    for (Cookie cookie : tagsFromCookie) {
        if (cookie.getName().contains(CREDENTIALS)) {
            tagPredicate.set("tagid",
                    (cookie.getValue().replaceAll("---", ":")));
                                            search.addPredicate(tagPredicate);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I have not used the `SimpleSearch` mechanism myself, but, the documentation states that you can can create a `PredicateGroup` (subclass of `Predicate`) containing multiple predicates, and can specify the logical operator (AND/OR) by calling `setAllRequired()`.

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/PredicateGroup.html

Perhaps you can try:

```
PredicateGroup group = new PredicateGroup("tags");

// This will set operator between each predicate to OR
group.setAllRequired(false);

Predicate tagPredicate = new Predicate("tags");
tagPredicate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OPERATION, JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OP_LIKE);
tagPredicate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.PROPERTY, "./jcr:content/cq:tags");
tagPredicate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.VALUE, cookieValue);
group.add(tagPredicate);

Predicate metaTagPredicate = new Predicate("metatags");
metaTagPredicate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OPERATION, JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.OP_LIKE);
metaTagPredicate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.PROPERTY, "./jcr:content/metadata/cq:tags");
metaTagPredicate.set(JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator.VALUE, cookieValue);
group.add(metaTagPredicate);

search.addPredicate(group);

// To debug and view your predicate tree you can invoke toString() on your predicate group
```

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that with the `JcrPropertyPredicateEvaluator`, you can perform an operation similar to `jcr:like()`.  For `jcr:contains()`, you will probably want to use the full text evaluator.

Alternatively, you could just directly build and execute a JCR query.  I find that it is much more straight forward than creating Predicates and using the `QueryBuilder API`.  Here is a very simple XPath example:

```
StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
queryBuilder.append("/jcr:root//*[jcr:contains(@cq:tags,");
queryBuilder.append(cookieValue);
queryBuilder.append(")] OR [jcr:contains(@metadata/cq:tags,");
queryBuilder.append(cookieValue);
queryBuilder.append(")]);

QueryManager manager = session.getWorkspace().getQueryManager();
Query query = manager.createQuery(queryBuilder.toString(), "xpath");
QueryResult result = query.execute();

// From the result you can then retrieve a NodeIterator to loop through the result set
```

http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/query/Query.html

Answer (score 0):

i would do a simple [jcr query](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolver.html#findResources%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for cq:tags property value of whatever node, so

```
//element(*, nt:unstructured)[@cq:tags=COOKIEVALUE]
```

You can then process the results to compute [the containing page](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/PageManager.html#getContainingPage%28org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource%29) or asset